# Появляется ошибка "'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)"!

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, кодировка

Здравствуйте у меня возникает ошибка "ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)" на сервере *Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab141.3 x86_64)* в то время как на *Windows 10* всё отлично. И возникает эта ошибка только тогда когда я пытаюсь вывести текст на русском языке!

Возможна ли что причина ошибки в версии python?
На Ubuntu сервере версия *python 3.5.2*
На Windows версия *3.8*

Как мне решить эту ошибку?

Comment: Приведите код, в котором возникает проблема

Comment: Да в любом коде в котором я пытаюсь вывести текст на русском языке.

Comment: Даже на `print('привет')`? Тогда, возможно, у вас в системе не настроены язык и кодировка по умолчанию, проверьте значение переменной окружения `LANG` и сделайте `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: Вот тот код: https://pastebin.com/x7i833EK